# Only print records that have a matching field after using a record separator

Tags: regex, awk, grep

I have a bunch of records, and I only want to see the records where a field (or multiple fields) match a regex pattern.

For example, say my data comes in a form like this:

```
Time=181 ms
RequestId=12345
Method=GET
... # other records
EndTime=Tue Mar 5 16:21:03 2015 UTC
EOE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Time=4003 ms
RequestId=53224
Method=POST
... # other records
EndTime=Tue Mar 5 16:21:09 2015 UTC
EOE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The way I have done it before is to use `grep` with the `-A` and `-B` flags to extract context.

```
zgrep "16:2[0-5]:" -A 1 -B 10 data.txt
```

This works fine if I am looking for a single pattern and each record has the same amount of lines, but becomes more complicated once I have to look for multiple fields with their own patterns.

What I want to do is separate each one of these inputs into a record and then only print each record of 1 or more of the fields match the pattern I am looking for.

I can split them into records using the `RS`, but how would I only print records that have different parts matching? Say if I wanted to find all records that have an `EndTime` between `16:20` and `16:30` and the `Time` was longer than 1 second (`[0-9]{4,}`) when there could be an arbitrary amount of rows in between?

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS = "EOE" } { ??? }' data.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your main issue is how to access the data, not how to test it after you've got it, so: whenever you have name=value pairs in the input it's a good idea to construct a name2value array and then you can just access the values by name:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { RS="\nEOE\n-+\n"; FS="\n"; OFS="," }
{
    delete n2v
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        name = gensub(/=.*$/,"","",$i)
        value = gensub(/[^=]+=/,"","",$i)
        n2v[name] = value
    }
    print n2v["Time"], n2v["RequestId"], n2v["Method"], n2v["EndTime"]
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
181 ms,12345,GET,Tue Mar 5 16:21:03 2015 UTC
4003 ms,53224,POST,Tue Mar 5 16:21:09 2015 UTC
```

The above uses some GNU awk extensions. Use the gawk time functions for any time math you need to do.